# passing function statement as string in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

is it possible to somehow pass and decode the variable in quotes from main.tf to test.tf.

I am trying to do some calculation. But it is different for all the modules.
I am wondering is we can pass something like this from one file:

- main.tf

```
test = "length(regexall(\"file\", each.key)) > 0 ? [for n in var.dns : n][0] : [for n in var.dns : n][1]"
```

- test.tf

Read it in other without quotes and escape character??

```
test = length(regexall("file", each.key)) > 0 ? [for n in var.dns : n][0] : [for n in var.dns : n][1]
```

I already tried using replace and trim. It isn't working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly such a thing is **not supported** in terraform. You can't dynamically pass TF code as strings and then evaluate the string as a code, like `eval` in other languages.

The closest would to use [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which you program yourself. Since you have to develop it, you can program any logic you want.